# Spring Security 4.0.1 Sample Contacts Deployment Issue

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, contacts

I am deploying contacts-xml.war into JBOSS EAP 6.4.0. Deployment says it started however I have an error which may not be the issue I have.

`12:03:55,612 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 162) SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
12:03:55,616 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 162) Failed to drop tables: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DROP TABLE CONTACTS]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: CONTACTS in statement [DROP TABLE CONTACTS]`

Issue:
I am unable to access http://localhost:8080/contacts URL. The web.xml has correctly configured this and does gets deployed:

`12:03:56,724 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 162) Mapped URL path [/frames.htm] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
12:03:56,739 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 162) FrameworkServlet 'contacts': initialization completed in 312 ms`

I do have the deployments done information on console:

`12:03:56,791 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS015859: Deployed "contacts-xml.war" (runtime-name : "contacts-xml.war")`

Why is the URL not accessible?
Why am I having that DROP table error? [hsqldb]
Is there a How to use / user guide for this sample app?

Comment: Probably you are not having welcome page configured, try with some other url.

Comment: I figured it out. Checking out from Spring-Security samples, it exports as "contacts-xml" as the maven project and war name. But the web.xml has defined the application name mapped to servlet name "contacts". So, I changed the project name to contacts. Problem solved. But I am not sure about the SQL grammar exception. It could be the way they coded to drop tables even if it does not exists.